# Operator || cannot be applied to type bool and string / string and string

Tags: c#, string, if-statement

Simple task that I am finding really difficult.

```
 Console.Write("[" + CurrentTime + "] Name a day of the week? ");
 string vDay = Console.ReadLine();
 if (vDay != "Monday" || "Tuesday" || "Wednesday" || "Thursday" || "Friday")
 {
  Console.WriteLine("that is not a valid day of the week");
 }
```

Firsty when I use != it gives me an error saying "cannot be applied to bool and string" without the != and just the = I get "string and string"

Basically what I am trying to do is if someone types "hello" for example it will say that is not a valid day of the week.

Such a simple task but im finding it so difficult, thanks for any help.

Comment: You could do something else entirely:             List<String> validDays = new List<string> { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };
            if (!validDays.Contains(vDay))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since all the answers here do not explain why you are facing that problem in the first place, I shall attempt to do so.

> when I use != it gives me an error saying "cannot be applied to bool
>   and string"

This is because, in your code:

```
...vDay != "Monday" || "Tuesday" ...
```

`vDay` is compared to string "Monday" which evaluates successfully and then the result (which is boolean) is compared to string "Tuesday". This gives you the problem of "*...cannot be applied to bool and string..*"

> without the != and just the = I get "string and string

`vDay` is being assigned the value of "Monday" (which could result in string "Monday") however the string "Monday" is being compared with string "Tuesday". This gives you the problem of "*...cannot be applied to string and string..*".

The correct way would be to specify operators separately:

```
...vDay != "Monday" && vDay != "Tuesday"...
```

Or using the other ways as best described by other answers.

Answer (score 8):

Might be cleaner to have something like:

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", ... };

if (!list.Contains(vDay ))
{
    Console.WriteLine("that is not a valid day of the week");
}
```

Comment: This is ok. But it doesn't answer the Op's original problem of why the  error says "cannot be applied to bool and string".

Answer (score 6):

This is what you need:

```
if (vDay != "Monday" && vDay != "Tuesday" && vDay != "Wednesday" && vDay != "Thursday" && vDay != "Friday")
{
      Console.WriteLine("that is not a valid day of the week");
}
```

Comment: or check with [List.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/bhkz42b3(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Ah so for each one. i get it now, thank you very much :)

Comment: @al-Acme: You may want to explain a bit to the Op, why the error says "*cannot be applied to bool and string*"

Comment: Need to use && not || here to keep the logic.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Indeed, otherwise it will be always `true`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another take, using set-based logic.

```
 var days = new HashSet<string> { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };
 if (!days.Contains(vDay))
 {
    Console.WriteLine("that is not a valid day of the week");
 }
```

**Edit**

I guess to explain the error:

[`Operator !=` on `String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_inequality%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) accepts only a single string on the RHS of the operator, and neither does C# support `List` creation through the logical or `||` operator (if this is what was intended, nor conversely, projection of the != operator across the `||`ed strings). However, a set can be created and set operations such as `Contains` can be used. `Hashset` would typically be my first choice in such a scenario, as it acts as an indexed lookup (although arguably overkill for a set of ~5 strings, this will scale much better than `List` or `Array` for much larger sets).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (vDay == "Monday" ||vDay == "Tuesday" ||vDay == "Wednesday" ||vDay == "Thursday" ||vDay == "Friday")
 {
  Console.WriteLine("is not a valid day of the week");
 }
```

This should do it.

Answer (score -2):

```
Text='<%# Eval("STS").ToString() == "N" ||Eval("STS").ToString() =="R"  ? "<h5>Approve?</h5>" : "<h5>Approved!</h5>"  %>'
```

Comment: Can you turn this into something of a helpful answer? It is unreadable, code-only (at most) and afaict totally unrelated.